# Can product of distinct $\frac{3m+2}{2m+1}$ be an integer?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Friend gave me this problem (although I don't think he knows the answer). The question is whether the product
$$
\frac{3m_1+2}{2m_1+1}\cdot\frac{3m_2+2}{2m_2+1}\cdots \frac{3m_n+2}{2m_n+1}
$$
can be an integer for some distinct $m_i \in \mathbb{N}$ (here $0 \not\in \mathbb{N}$, otherwise we would have simple solution $n=1, m_1=0$, giving product $2$). So basically this is about products of combinations of numbers
$$
\frac{5}{3},\frac{8}{5},\frac{11}{7},\frac{14}{9}, \frac{17}{11}, \frac{20}{13}, \frac{23}{15}, \frac{26}{17}, \frac{29}{19}, \frac{32}{21}, \dots
$$

**My try so far:**

We can rule out fractions which have denominator divisible by $3$, since no numerator can be divisible by $3$, so basically $m \not\equiv 1 \pmod 3$. I have then tried computer checking all products with $m_i \in \{2,3,5,6,8,9,\dots,39\}$, none of them yield an integer.

Comment: Preliminary ideas: It's trivial to see that no product of two $m_k$'s is an integer, and some deduction shows that no product of three $m_k$'s is an integer, either.

Comment: No product of four $m_k$'s, either.

Comment: I wrote a small program that tests whether the value is an integer and the first result of this occurring when $m_1=2$ and $m_i=m_{i-1}+1$ is when $m_n=82$ giving a result of $338480466710618$. I suspect you want a more mathematically based answer, however.

Comment: @CooperCape That would be alright, but I don't see how it works, since for example $m_3=4$ and so $2m_3+1=9$ is divisible by $3$, and there can be no corresponding numerator in which this would cancel (none of them is divisible by $3$). Are you sure your result is correct?

Comment: Okay, give me one sec, I'll check it numerically.

Comment: @Sil Yes you're right, in fact the number is so big it gave up on giving me digits at $m=82$, I'll try and correct that. Apologies I should've been more thorough.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are solutions for many values of $n$.
You can find here solutions for $n=5,\;\;7,8,9,10,\ldots, 21$.

One of solutions for $n=5$:

$$
(m_1,m_2,m_3,m_4,m_5)=(9,12,14,27,41):
$$

$$
\dfrac{3\cdot 9+2}{2\cdot 9 + 1} \times
\dfrac{3\cdot 12+2}{2\cdot 12 + 1} \times
\dfrac{3\cdot 14+2}{2\cdot 14 + 1} \times
\dfrac{3\cdot 27+2}{2\cdot 27 + 1} \times
\dfrac{3\cdot 41+2}{2\cdot 41 + 1} = \\
\dfrac{\color{red}{29}}{\color{violet}{19}} \times \dfrac{\color{violet}{38}}{\color{blue}{25}} \times \dfrac{44}{\color{red}{29}}
\times \dfrac{\color{green}{83}}{55} \times \dfrac{\color{blue}{125}}{\color{green}{83}} =
\\ \dfrac{503063000}{62882875} = 
8.$$

Another examples of solutions for $n=5$:

$(9,12,14,21,71) \rightarrow 8$;

$(6,12,27,41,47) \rightarrow 8$;

$(6,12,21,47,71) \rightarrow 8$;

$(9, 11, 12, 30, 101) \rightarrow 8$;

$(8, 9, 14, 71, 107) \rightarrow 8$;

$(6, 8, 47, 71, 107) \rightarrow 8$;

$(5, 12, 41, 47, 110) \rightarrow 8$;

$(6, 8, 39, 87, 131) \rightarrow 8$;

$(6, 11, 17, 99, 132) \rightarrow 8$;

$(3, 99, 123, 126, 132) \rightarrow 8$;

$\ldots$

$(3,30,1943,5351,5652) \rightarrow 8$;

$(3,30,2081,4371,5912) \rightarrow 8$;

$(3,30,2133,4680,5103) \rightarrow 8$;

$\ldots$

---

Now focus on $n\ge 7$.
For each $n\ge 7$ we search integer solution $q, (m_1,m_2,\ldots,m_n)$ for equation
$$
\prod_{j=1}^n \dfrac{3m_j+2}{2m_j+1} = q \tag{*}.
$$

For each $n\ge 7$ there are many solutions of eq. $(*)$.
Few examples with rather small values $m_j$:

```
  n     q       (m_1, m_2, ..., m_n)
```

---

```
  7     19      (3,5,11,23,35,53,297)
  7     19      (3,5,9,23,35,297,1551)
  7     19      (3,5,11,17,53,59,4743)
 ...    ...     ...
```

---

```
  8     26      (21,71,147,221,237,255,267,356)
  8     28      (3,8,27,32,41,47,71,107)
 ...    ...     ...
```

---

```
  9     40      (12,27,41,45,47,51,68,81,108)
  9     41      (3,21,47,71,137,147,221,227,341)
  9     43      (3,5,15,17,23,35,53,501,609)
  9     44      (3,5,8,11,12,27,41,201,237)
 ...    ...     ...
```

---

```
  10    58      (57,123,605,671,753,821,1004,1079,1145,1227)
  10    59      (21,27,47,71,207,297,305,311,327,491)
  10    61      (5,11,47,69,71,107,161,339,467,509)
  10    62      (3,27,29,41,47,71,107,137,144,311)
  10    64      (6,8,9,12,14,27,41,47,71,107)
  10    65      (3,5,11,15,23,35,53,57,605,671)
 ...    ...     ...
```

---

```
  11    88      (47,71,81,87,107,108,131,144,197,296,311)
  11    89      (21,27,41,47,71,137,147,201,221,237,563) 
  11    91      (5,21,23,71,177,201,297,389,417,447,671) 
  11    92      (8,15,23,35,39,45,51,53,68,87,131)
  11    94      (5,8,11,17,47,71,107,201,237,291,297)
  11    95      (3,5,21,47,71,147,221,297,305,327,491)
  11    98      (3,5,8,11,21,71,137,147,201,221,237)
  11    100     (3,5,8,11,15,20,23,35,53,227,341)
  11    104     (2,3,5,11,15,23,35,53,59,447,671)
 ...    ...     ...
```

---

```
  12    131     (47,107,123,291,297,311,467,563,579,587,963,1091)
  12    134     (9,21,71,164,227,297,333,341,389,417,447,513)
  12    136     (11,15,23,35,53,87,131,144,192,197,296,311)
  12    139     (3,21,39,71,87,131,137,147,161,221,339,509)
  12    140     (9,11,12,15,20,23,101,177,201,237,291,335)
  12    142     (3,11,15,23,35,53,72,357,381,795,801,1017)
  12    143     (3,11,15,23,27,35,53,87,131,207,311,671)
  12    145     (3,5,9,23,35,53,297,333,351,357,527,791)
  12    146     (3,5,11,15,23,35,53,237,501,563,845,924)
  12    148     (3,5,8,15,23,32,35,51,53,171,333,357)
  12    160     (2,3,5,8,11,15,20,23,35,53,227,341)
 ...    ...     ...
```

---

```
  13    199     (21,39,71,87,131,137,147,201,221,465,671,1079,1127)
  13    200     (21,27,41,71,87,131,197,212,296,311,333,357,536)
  13    202     (8,27,41,71,107,201,237,287,351,431,437,527,791)
  13    203     (9,23,35,47,53,71,107,297,333,351,357,527,791)
  13    205     (9,11,23,35,53,101,107,297,351,527,579,587,791)
  13    206     (5,21,27,41,47,71,201,237,287,297,431,869,1304)
  13    208     (6,8,21,39,71,87,131,147,221,237,255,267,356)
  13    211     (3,11,27,39,41,87,131,237,263,395,593,753,773)
  13    212     (9,11,12,15,20,21,23,71,101,177,201,237,335)
  13    214     (3,5,21,47,71,87,131,297,305,671,851,1131,1212)
  13    215     (3,5,21,27,41,137,147,201,221,237,501,609,759)
  13    217     (3,5,11,23,35,53,227,297,341,389,417,447,671)
  13    220     (3,5,11,15,23,35,53,87,131,144,197,296,311)
  13    224     (3,5,8,11,12,27,41,99,123,132,149,168,224)
 ...    ...     ...
```

---

```
  14    295     (51,137,147,171,201,221,389,417,423,447,671,821,971,1317)
  14    296     (51,77,116,137,147,171,212,221,275,311,413,620,731,1097)
  14    302     (9,21,71,107,159,201,237,239,359,563,620,705,845,855)
  14    304     (8,27,41,71,107,137,147,201,206,221,237,255,267,356)
  14    305     (9,17,21,71,137,147,201,221,237,291,297,333,345,1151)
  14    308     (8,21,27,39,41,71,80,87,131,137,147,201,221,237)
  14    310     (9,12,21,27,41,47,71,101,107,201,237,335,501,609)
  14    311     (3,21,71,137,147,201,221,237,287,291,431,647,971,1347)
  14    316     (3,8,39,87,131,137,147,221,227,341,389,416,417,447)
  14    320     (6,11,12,15,23,35,47,51,53,71,107,161,171,242) 
  14    322     (3,11,15,23,35,51,53,60,87,131,171,179,513,837)
  14    323     (3,11,15,23,27,35,41,53,137,147,221,237,311,563)
  14    328     (3,9,11,12,27,30,41,47,101,137,147,221,227,341)
  14    332     (3,5,9,12,27,41,47,71,107,144,159,201,239,359)
  14    344     (2,3,11,15,23,27,35,41,53,107,237,501,609,759)
  14    352     (2,3,5,11,15,23,35,53,87,131,144,197,296,311)
 ...    ...     ...
```

---

```
  15    448     (21,71,77,80,116,137,147,206,221,237,255,267,356,357,536)
  15    452     (8,71,87,107,131,197,201,237,291,296,333,357,489,759,795)
  15    455     (9,21,47,71,101,137,147,201,221,335,423,471,707,927,1061)
  15    458     (8,27,39,41,71,87,107,131,201,203,237,333,357,381,399)
  15    460     (9,12,21,71,101,137,147,201,221,237,291,333,335,444,465)
  15    464     (8,9,27,41,71,80,107,147,221,237,255,267,356,396,467)
  15    470     (9,11,15,17,23,35,53,237,291,297,311,333,357,536,563)
  15    472     (8,11,15,23,35,45,51,53,68,71,107,212,255,275,413)
  15    476     (3,11,27,41,47,71,107,147,221,237,255,267,356,357,536)
  15    481     (3,11,15,23,35,51,53,137,171,333,357,383,575,863,1295)
  15    484     (3,11,15,23,27,35,41,53,164,237,287,344,431,759,795)
  15    485     (3,11,15,17,23,35,53,71,107,237,291,333,705,857,1131)
  15    488     (3,9,12,21,27,32,41,71,87,131,197,296,311,333,467)
  15    490     (3,5,8,21,71,137,147,201,221,227,237,341,471,707,1061)
  15    496     (3,5,8,27,32,41,47,63,84,95,143,164,215,323,485)
  15    508     (3,5,8,11,15,20,23,35,53,71,107,465,1079,1145,1227)
  15    512     (3,6,9,11,12,14,21,27,41,62,71,99,117,132,176)
 ...    ...     ...
```

---

```
  16    676     (21,27,41,71,80,137,147,221,237,255,267,356,383,575,863,1295)
  16    680     (9,21,71,137,147,201,221,237,333,395,489,563,591,593,674,753)
  16    682     (9,15,51,107,171,305,327,333,467,491,501,579,587,753,795,1004)
  16    686     (8,21,39,71,87,131,137,147,201,221,237,287,291,431,759,795)
  16    688     (8,27,39,41,71,80,87,131,147,221,237,255,267,356,396,467)
  16    692     (8,9,39,71,87,107,131,201,237,291,333,335,467,521,1092,1095)
  16    700     (9,15,23,27,35,41,51,53,80,137,147,171,221,333,396,467)
  16    704     (9,12,23,27,35,41,47,53,71,80,107,110,203,207,246,311)
  16    710     (9,11,12,15,23,35,51,53,171,227,341,389,417,447,449,671)
  16    712     (9,11,12,15,23,35,51,53,87,131,171,207,276,333,375,500)
  16    716     (3,23,27,35,41,47,53,57,71,86,107,227,297,341,389,417)
  16    728     (3,11,15,17,23,35,53,71,107,237,291,333,444,465,620,632)
  16    736     (3,5,8,45,51,68,77,116,135,137,180,240,383,575,863,1295)
  16    742     (3,5,8,21,27,41,71,137,147,201,221,237,287,431,647,971)
  16    752     (3,5,8,15,23,32,35,51,53,57,171,333,357,536,605,908)
  16    760     (3,5,8,11,15,23,32,35,53,87,131,171,669,671,717,1076)
 ...    ...     ...
```

---

```
  17    1024    (8,47,71,77,107,116,141,144,188,192,212,216,227,288,341,384,512)
  17    1028    (9,21,35,53,71,87,131,197,296,311,333,357,449,609,812,1091,1113)
  17    1034    (8,27,39,41,47,71,87,107,131,147,201,221,467,579,609,759,795)
  17    1036    (9,21,23,35,53,71,80,137,147,221,275,297,381,413,617,620,801)
  17    1040    (8,15,39,45,51,68,81,87,108,131,164,227,341,389,417,447,671)
  17    1048    (9,15,23,27,35,41,53,80,101,137,147,221,237,396,563,567,756)
  17    1052    (6,11,23,35,47,53,71,107,171,297,389,417,447,669,671,759,1139)
  17    1054    (9,11,12,21,27,71,101,201,207,237,311,335,437,501,609,881,1161)
  17    1060    (9,12,15,21,23,35,51,53,71,171,287,333,431,435,513,653,684)
  17    1064    (9,11,12,21,23,35,53,71,87,131,197,296,297,311,333,375,500)
  17    1072    (3,23,27,35,41,47,53,71,107,144,192,201,203,246,287,431,647)
  17    1088    (3,15,23,27,35,41,47,53,57,71,86,107,110,144,192,207,311)
  17    1096    (3,9,12,21,27,41,53,71,80,159,239,249,332,359,539,809,867)
  17    1100    (3,11,12,15,23,35,51,53,60,171,201,237,287,291,431,647,971)
  17    1136    (3,5,8,11,15,23,35,53,71,107,237,333,357,416,462,867,1301)
 ...    ...     ...
```

---

```
  18    1544    (8,21,39,71,87,131,147,201,221,237,255,267,356,396,423,467,471,707)
  18    1552    (8,11,71,99,107,123,132,137,147,171,201,221,237,333,566,705,857,1131)
  18    1568    (8,11,21,39,71,87,131,137,147,201,206,221,237,255,267,356,375,500)
  18    1580    (8,15,23,27,35,41,51,53,80,137,147,171,221,227,341,389,417,447)
  18    1592    (6,8,27,39,41,47,71,87,107,131,137,147,201,221,465,671,1079,1127)
  18    1600    (9,12,15,23,27,35,41,47,53,71,101,107,126,212,237,333,396,416)
  18    1616    (9,11,12,15,21,23,35,53,71,80,101,137,147,221,237,396,416,437)
  18    1664    (6,8,9,12,14,21,27,39,41,71,87,131,147,221,237,255,267,356)
  18    1696    (3,5,11,12,15,23,35,51,53,171,237,263,282,291,333,357,647,971)
 ...    ...     ...
```

---

```
  19    2336    (6,15,41,47,137,147,164,221,227,237,276,341,389,417,447,501,563,845,924)
  19    2366    (9,15,23,27,35,41,51,53,80,137,147,171,221,237,263,333,395,593,753)
  19    2368    (6,8,39,51,77,87,116,131,137,147,171,212,221,275,311,413,620,731,1097)
  19    2380    (8,11,15,23,35,51,53,71,107,171,179,237,287,431,759,795,821,837,1116)
  19    2384    (8,11,12,27,41,47,71,87,107,131,197,201,237,291,296,311,335,467,1092)
  19    2392    (9,12,15,21,23,35,53,71,80,81,101,108,237,335,423,471,707,927,1061)
  19    2432    (9,12,14,15,23,27,35,41,45,51,53,68,83,125,222,333,357,536,563)
  19    2560    (3,5,8,11,15,23,35,53,87,131,144,192,197,296,311,396,467,977,1466)
 ...    ...     ...
```

---

```
  20    3500    (9,21,23,35,53,71,80,137,147,221,227,297,341,389,417,447,671,821,971)
  20    3520    (8,15,39,45,51,68,81,87,108,117,131,176,185,237,278,287,291,431,759,795)
  20    3584    (6,11,24,27,41,47,69,92,99,123,126,132,147,221,237,255,267,356,357,536)
 ...    ...     ...
```

---

```
  21    5488    (6,11,15,17,21,23,35,53,71,80,99,132,137,147,171,221,237,471,669,707,1061)
  21    5504    (9,12,14,15,23,27,35,41,45,51,53,57,68,80,86,137,147,221,237,291,759)
```

*Note 1*: if $n\ge 8$, then eq. $(*)$ has solutions for different integer $q$.

*Note 2*: this integer product is divisible by $2$, $4$, $8$ in many cases
(depends on parity of numbers $m_j$); solutions with odd $q$ exist too, but are much more rare.

Comment: Nice! How did you find those? Looks strange that all of those are $8$ :o

Comment: @Sil: thanks! Simple computer search; yes, strange for me too; (and additional info: no solutions for $n=6$ (with $m_j>0$) and no solutions for $n=7$ so far..).

Comment: @sil: Each fraction is slightly bigger than $\frac{3}{2}$, and $(3/2)^5 \approx 7.6$. A product of five such fractions is going to be a little larger than $7.6$, so you'd expect most examples with five terms to have a product of $8$.

Comment: @Oleg567 $n≠6,9,12$ since all numerators are not divisible by $3$.

Comment: @AlexFrancisco Could you elaborate? I don't see why $\Pi_{k=1}^n 2m_k + 1$ would be a multiple of $3$ if $n=6$ (for example if all $m_k$ are $0 \mod 3$ the product will be $1 \mod 3$). Or is there another reason than the denominator being a multiple of $3$?

Comment: @Hurkyl Interesting observation. Thought about it and we also we have upper bound $\frac{8}{5}\frac{11}{7}\frac{17}{11}\frac{20}{13}\frac{26}{17}=\frac{64}{7}=9.14$ (since the $f(m)=\frac{3m+2}{2m+1}$ is decreasing), so really only possible values are $8,9$ for $n=5$. And with increasing $m$'s, this goes down, so already if smallest $m$ is $\geq 3$, the upper bound is less then $9$, so... This way also we need smallest $m\leq 14$ to have any solution (still for $n=5$).

Comment: @Alex: agree with "$n\ne 6$", but there are solutions for $9,12,15,18$.

Comment: @Sil: if you are interested in $n>5$ then you can see few solutions for $n\ge 8$ in updated answer. (And thanks to you and to your friend for interesting problem).

Comment: @Oleg567 I mixed the meaning of $n$. There I meant the product cannot be divisible by $3$.